# On scroll, logo color changes, but scrolling back up it stays the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Im creating a fixed header where on load, the logo is flat white. On scroll, it changes to the full color logo.
However, when scrolling back to the top, it stays the same colored logo instead of going back to white.
Here's the code (and a pen)

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var navlogo = $('.nav-logo-before');
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 1) {
        navlogo.removeClass('.nav-logo-before').addClass('nav-logo-after');

    } else  {
        navlogo.removeClass('.nav-logo-after').addClass('nav-logo-before');            
    }

});
```

});

http://codepen.io/bradpaulp/pen/gmXOjG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing the class `nav-logo-before`, so the second time the function runs, it can't find any element with `nav-logo-before`.

Just give a second class to your navlogo element and use that on line 3.
Like this:

```
var navlogo = $('.second-class');
```

working example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryYajx

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! (I upvoted your comment, but it wouldn't take since I'm new to stackoverflow)

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this solution is the correct one, you should mark this as the "accepted answer". The button is below the downvote icon.

Answer (score 1):

Dont need to add the dot . in front of the class name in removeClass and addClass:
Use this:

```
navlogo.removeClass('nav-logo-before')
```

Secondly, you are removing the class that you are using to get the element in the first place.

I have an updated codepen, see if this suits your needs: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeaYRO

Comment: This is only one of the problems

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Good, I removed the downvote, I still wish the OP sees my answer as I think there's some more important information.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! As did another solution offered here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things here:

1) You start with a .nav-logo-before class but when the logo becomes black you remove that class and then try to get the same element using a class selector that doesn't exist anymore

2) `removeClass('.nav-logo-before')` is different than `removeClass('nev-logo-before)`, notice the "." in the first selector.

3) You get the element using the `$('.selector')`in every scroll event, this can be a performance issue, it's better to cache them on page load and then use the element stored in memory

4) It's not a good practice to listen to scroll events as this can be too performance demanding, it's usually better to use the `requestAnimationFrame` and then check if the scroll position has changed. Using the scroll event it could happen that you scroll up really fast and the scroll event doesn't happen at 0, so your logo won't change. With `requestAnimationFrame` this can't happen

```js
$(function() {
    var navlogo = $('.nav-logo');
    var $window = $(window);
    var oldScroll = 0;
    function loop() { 
        var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
        if (oldScroll != scroll) {
            oldScroll = scroll;
            if (scroll >= 1) {
                navlogo.removeClass('nav-logo-before').addClass('nav-logo-after');
            } else  {
                navlogo.removeClass('nav-logo-after').addClass('nav-logo-before');      
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.space {
 padding: 300px;
}
.nav-logo-before {
    content: url(https://image.ibb.co/kYANyv/logo_test_before.png)
}

.nav-logo-after {
    content: url(https://image.ibb.co/jYzFJv/logo_test_after.png)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <img class="nav-logo nav-logo-before">
</div>
<div class="space">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the navlogo variable using

```
var navlogo = $('.nav-logo-before');
```

but then you change the class to be 'nav-logo-after', so next time the function gets called you won't be able to select the logo using jquery as it won't have the '.nav-logo-before'class anymore.

You could add an id to the logo and use that to select it, for example.

Apart from that, `removeClass('.nav-logo-before')` should be `removeClass('nav-logo-before')` without the dot before the class name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you removes `nav-logo-before` and then you want to select element with such class but it doesn't exist.

I've rafactored you code to avert it.

Another problem is that you uses dot in `removeClass('.before')` while it should be `removeClass('before')` - without dot

```js
$(function() { 

    var navlogo = $('.nav-logo');
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
        if (scroll >= 1) {
            navlogo.removeClass('before').addClass('after');
            
        } else  {
            navlogo.removeClass('after').addClass('before');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.space {
 padding: 300px;
}
.before {
    content: url(https://image.ibb.co/kYANyv/logo_test_before.png)
}

.after {
    content: url(https://image.ibb.co/jYzFJv/logo_test_after.png)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <img class="nav-logo before">
</div>
<div class="space">
</div>
```